# Can I force memory usage of vespa-proton-bin?

Tags: vespa

I found `vespa-proton-bin` already used 68GB memory of my system. I've tried to limit memory on docker level and found that it will randomly kill process, which can be a huge problem.

Is there any setting to force it just using certain amount of memory on `vespa-proton-bin` in Vespa setting? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Great question!

There is no explicit way to tell Vespa to only use x GB of memory but default Vespa will block feeding if 80% of the memory is in use already, see https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/writing-to-vespa.html#feed-block. Using docker limits is only going to cause random OOM kills which is not what you want. 
I'm guessing that you have a lot of attribute fields which are in-memory structures , see https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/performance/attribute-memory-usage.html.